# Hibernate hbm2ddl issue

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

I'm developing a new hibernate project. By defining `*.hbm.xml` I want to generate java class and SQL query. I have done that. I am not able to generate alter table query upon setting `hbm2ddl.auto` property to update. I have tried this in persistence.xml file and also in hibernate.cfg.xml file. Also tried with true in pom.xml from , that did not work. Please share your thoughts on this. When this update is set to true in `pom.xml` hbm2ddl goal does not generate the query too.